# Serial.read() - XBee - not firing 'else if'

Tags: arduino, xbee

I am currently trying to do some communication test between a PC and [Arduino Uno](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno) using an XBee in AT mode.

My test is to send characters from the computer to the XBee and process through conditional statements.

I don't believe this issue is with configuration of the XBees, for I am able to communicate successfully when I watch the Serial monitors.

Here is the code I am running on the Arduino:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial xBee = SoftwareSerial(1, 0);

int Led = 9;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(Led, OUTPUT);
  xBee.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  if (xBee.available()> 0)
  {
    if (xBee.read() == 'r')
    {
       digitalWrite(Led, HIGH);
       xBee.write("Led On");
       delay(10);
    }
    else if (xBee.read() == 'o')
    {
      digitalWrite(Led, LOW);
      xBee.write("Led Off");
      delay(10);
    }
    else
    {
      xBee.write("NR"); // Testing for not recognized characters
    }
    delay(10);
  }
  delay(10);
}
```

I can turn on the LED when sending the character 'r' from the PC to the XBee. The intended result is received back as well. When I try to send the character 'o' from the PC the LED stays on, and I get the response of "NR".

This same result happens with different characters in the else if statement, sending character 'o' as the first character, changing to just if statements, and changing the initial condition to - while xBee.available().

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: You'll want to read once, store that in a variable, then use the variable in your if/else if conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store the input value of `xBee.read()` and then use it in the `if` condition.

You can try this

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial xBee = SoftwareSerial(1, 0);

int Led = 9;

void setup()  
{
  pinMode(Led, OUTPUT);
  xBee.begin(9600);  
}

void loop()
{ 
  char read_value = xBee.read();
  if(xBee.available()> 0) 
  {

    if ( read_value == 'r')
    {
       digitalWrite(Led, HIGH);
       xBee.write("Led On");
       delay(10);       
    }
    else if ( read_value == 'o')
    {
      digitalWrite(Led, LOW);   
      xBee.write("Led Off");
      delay(10);      
    }
    else
    {
      xBee.write("NR"); // Testing for not recognized characters
    }
    delay(10);
  }
  delay(10);

}
```

The problem is that you are taking the input with `xBee.read()` but not storing it.

Only your first `if` works ie,

```
 if ( read_value == 'r')
    {
       digitalWrite(Led, HIGH);
       xBee.write("Led On");
       delay(10);       
    }
```

The control is not even going in the `else if` hence condition for o is not tested.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, don't know why that eluded me. I had to move the read_value within the first nest of the loop for the conditions to be able to fire correctly